# .net core MVC app on Azure: how to limit access

Tags: sql-server, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cloud

I've just uploaded my first app on Azure: it is a .net core MVC site + webapi + sql server. This app will be used by one user.

How can I limit the access to the app using a login, without developing that part on .net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One service you could use for this is [App Service Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization).

> Azure App Service provides built-in authentication and authorization support, so you can sign in users and access data by writing minimal or no code in your web app, RESTful API, and mobile back end, and also Azure Functions.

If the user is from a specific location, you could also look into how you can configure [Azure App Service Access Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).